# ArrayList vs. Array. Why is one working and one isn't?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I've been trying to switch an older assignment over from an array to an `arraylist`, but for whatever reason my find method is not working when I modify it to use `arrayList`.. Seems to always be returning `-1`.

This is part of a large class so I don't want to include everything unless completely necessary, but I did include the declarations in case they are important:

```
public class Switch {
    private SwitchEntry[] camTable;
    private int numEntries;
    private int maxEntries;

public Switch() {
    camTable = new SwitchEntry[100];  // default value
    numEntries = 0;
    maxEntries = 100;
}

public Switch(int maxEntries) {
    camTable = new SwitchEntry[maxEntries];
    numEntries = 0;
    this.maxEntries = maxEntries;
}
```

Original:

```
public int find (MACAddress source) {
    int found = -1;
    for (int i=0; i < numEntries; i++)
        if (source.isEqual (camTable[i].getAddress())){
            found = i;
            break;
        }
    return found;               
}
```

Modified:

```
public int find (MACAddress source) {
    int found = -1;
    for (int i=0; i < numEntries; i++)
        if (source.isEqual (camTable.get(i).getAddress())){
            found = i;
            break;
        }
    return found;               
}
```

Where numEntries is modified & where the new entries are added into the arrayList:

```
public void processFrame(Frame inFrame) {
    // first, add source MAC to camTable if not already there
    if (find(inFrame.getSource()) == -1) {
        if (numEntries >= maxEntries) {
            System.out.println ("Error...camTable is full - cannot add " + inFrame.getSource());    
        } else { 
            camTable.add(new SwitchEntry(inFrame.getSource(), inFrame.getPort())); //PROBLEM LINE
            System.out.println ("Adding " + inFrame.getSource() + " to camTable");
        }
    }

    //process frame
    int index = find(inFrame.getDestination());
    if (index != -1){
        System.out.print ("Sending frame with data " + inFrame.getData() + " from " + inFrame.getSource() + " to " + inFrame.getDestination());
        System.out.println (" out port " + camTable.get(index).getPort() );
    } else {
        System.out.print ("Flooding frame with data " + inFrame.getData() + " from " + inFrame.getSource() + " to " + inFrame.getDestination());
        System.out.println (" out all ports"  );

    }

}
```

Solution:

```
camTable.add(numEntries++, new SwitchEntry(inFrame.getSource(),inFrame.getPort()));
```

Comment: where is arraylist ?

Comment: @VipinJain camTable is the arralist

Comment: @VipinJain in his `camTable.get(i)...` I believe. How are you getting `numEntries` Sentience? That maybe where the problem is. Also what is the `isEqual()` method?

Comment: @Sentience you need to debug why its coming -1

Comment: is camTable containing MACAddress object that will match and numEntries are greater than 0

Comment: I modified the question to include the arrayList, but camTable is it. Even if numEntries wasn't changing, wouldn't it still set found to 0?

Comment: Can you post the code where you are modifying the total `numEntries` and where you are declaring the `SwitchEntry[]`?

Comment: Please include the code where you initialize the arraylist and add elements to both

Comment: Will do, adding that now

Comment: I realize now where I made my mistake, when converting over I forgot to add the index at which the element is added. (originally numEntries++). I appreciate everyone's help in finding the solution!!!

Comment: @Sentience Okay, glad you found it. You can answer your question yourself, and even accept the answer, so that others can learn from it.

Answer (score 2):

Try This

```
public int find (MACAddress source) {
    int found = -1;
    ArrayList<MACAddress> camTable = new ArrayList<MACAddress>();
    ListIterator<MACAddress> itr = camTable.listIterator();
    while(itr.hasNext()){
        MACAddress tempAdd = itr.next();
        if(source.getAddress().equals(tempAdd.getAddress())){
            found = itr.nextIndex();
            return found;
        }
        return found;           
    }
```

I assume in ArrayList you store the objects of MACAddress. in if condition i check the source.getAddress to tempAdd.getAddress() is same then it will retun index of ArrayList. here `ArrayList` is `local variable` but you can create as a `class variable`

Comment: I appreciate you helping out but I solved the problem simply by adding numEntries++ into my camTable.add. If I had 15 reputation you would see an upvote... Unforunately I don't. :(

Answer (score 2):

Use Contain method of collection.(ArrayList)

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/arraylist_contains.htm

Answer (score 1):

Solution was straight-forward and just an oversight by me. All I had to do was add numEntries back into my add statement, which I neglected to fix after changing from an array to arrayList

Solution is posted in the original question now: